# Reduce performance time

Tags: vb.net

```
  'Check if the file has any broken records
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(fileDirectory)
        Dim fileLine As String
        Dim stopCheck As Boolean = False

        Do While reader.Peek() > -1
            fileLine = reader.ReadLine()

           'If the line is not start with eCW| then it is a broken record
            If Not fileLine.StartsWith("eCW|") Then
                stopCheck = True
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

        reader.Close()

        If stopCheck Then
```

It will take a very long time to validate the rows when the text file has many records.

ex.
File 1 has 500,000 completed records. It will looping through all the rows until it close the program.

File 2 has a broken records toward the end of text file. It will have to looping through all the rows before it find the broken record.

Is there a way to speed up this validation process?

Comment: This method is already very quick (have you measured the time requirements under the conditions you are proposing?). The problem with quicker methods is that they need the whole file to be loaded in memory what is not possible with too big files. On the other hand, when dealing with so many records, relying on files doesn't seem the best approach (databases are precisely meant for this kind of situations). Lastly, bear in mind that you have to dispose the `StreamReader` variable to avoid problems (e.g., file getting locked); you can easily take care of that with the `Using` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminating the use of the fileLine variable will eliminate a memory allocation on each iteration.

```
    Do While reader.Peek() > -1
       'If the line is not start with eCW| then it is a broken record
        If Not reader.ReadLine().StartsWith("eCW|") Then
            stopCheck = True
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
```

Since strings are immutable, a memory allocation takes place each time the string is changed. [Link](http://www.alexpolozov.com/blog/2014/9/28/on-performance-in-net) Other than this, I think your approach is great--once you add the `Using` statement that is.

Answer (score 1):

Just winging it here but ...

```
   try
       while not reader.readline().startswith("eCWL")
       end while
       stopCheck = true
    catch
       stopCheck = false
    end try
```

I'm guessing the catching the read exception when you try to read beyond eof will be well worth not needing to do the peek and the read for each record